# Unable to print the hashset element using Iterator for second time?

Tags: java, collections, printing, iterator, hashset

I need to print the hash set elements after removal of one element. using iterator and giving sysout doesn't work and giving sysout with hashset obj only prints it with element removed. why? 
If we are able to print the objects using sysout why iterator?

Below is my code :

```
package collectionprg;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RemoveElementHashSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        HashSet<Integer> hs= new HashSet<Integer>();

        hs.add(12);
        hs.add(234);
        hs.add(123);
        hs.add(12);


        Iterator<Integer> it = hs.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }


    System.out.println("afterremoval"); 

    hs.remove(234);

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }   

    System.out.println(hs);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you finish iterating over the element of the `HashSet` using the `Iterator`, `hasNext()` will always return `false`.

If you wish to perform a second iteration, you must create a second `Iterator` by calling `it = hs.iterator();` again.

```
// first iteration
Iterator<Integer> it = hs.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}

System.out.println("afterremoval"); 
hs.remove(234);

// second iteration
it = hs.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: After creating second iterator it worked. Thank you Eran.